# Rounding down values in Pandas dataframe column with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains a column of float64 values:

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [12,12,12,12,45,45,45,51,51,51,51,51,51,76,76,76,91,91,91,91],
                        'measure': [3.2,4.2,6.8,5.6,3.1,4.8,8.8,3.0,1.9,2.1,2.4,3.5,4.2,5.2,4.3,3.6,5.2,7.1,6.5,7.3]})
```

I want to create a new column containing just the integer part. My first thought was to use .astype(int):

```
tempDF['int_measure'] = tempDF['measure'].astype(int)
```

This works fine but, as an extra complication, the column I have contains a missing value:

```
tempDF.ix[10,'measure'] = np.nan
```

This missing value causes the .astype(int) method to fail with:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

I thought I could round down the floats in the column of data. However, the .round(0) function will round to the nearest integer (higher or lower) rather than rounding down. I can't find a function equivalent to ".floor()" that will act on a column of a Pandas dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In place of `NaN`, what value would be stored in `int_measure` column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could just apply `numpy.floor`;

```
import numpy as np

tempDF['int_measure'] = tempDF['measure'].apply(np.floor)

    id  measure  int_measure
0   12      3.2            3
1   12      4.2            4
2   12      6.8            6
...
9   51      2.1            2
10  51      NaN          NaN
11  51      3.5            3
...
19  91      7.3            7
```

Comment: I did search for a solution but missed that. Thanks very much for the rapid response.

Comment: Hello, I know this is an old thread, but I have run into a problem where I am trying to do the same thing but with the ceiling function. I am trying to round up to the nearest integer for a Pandas dataframe. I did this:

df['miles'].apply(np.ceil)

And it returns:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ceil'

Comment: FYI, if anyone stumbles upon my question with a similar problem... The problem was I had some NaN values in my series. I converted them using np.nan_to_num and it fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s // 1)
```

Using `np.floor` is faster, however.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are pretty dated and as of pandas 0.25.2 (perhaps earlier) the error

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Which would be

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].astype(int)
```

for one particular column.